# react-modal won't close after onClick event from another component

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

first time exploring Gatsby and tried to install [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal). Added modal component inside my *ComponentOne* and inside the modal is another component which is *ComponentTwo* where the close trigger resides. Already passed the `onClick` to *ComponentTwo* but still no luck. I think I miss something.

**ComponentOne**

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import ComponentTwo from "./ComponentTwo"
import Modal from 'react-modal'

export default class ComponentOne extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };

    this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
    this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
  }

  handleOpenModal() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  handleCloseModal() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container mx-auto h-50">
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.showModal}
          ariaHideApp={false}
          style={cotentStyle}
        >
          <ComponentTwo onClick={this.handleCloseModal} /> // this is component two
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**ComponentTwo**

```
import React from 'react'
import { TiDelete } from 'react-icons/ti'

const NavContent = ({ data }, props) => (
  <>
    <div className="bg-black z-10 absolute inset-0">
        <button onClick={props.onClick} className="text-white absolute top-0 right-0 my-4 mx-4">
          <TiDelete size={'2em'} />
        </button>
    </div>
  </>
)

export default function Nav(props) {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={worksQuery}
      render={data => <NavContent data={data} {...props} />}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
export default function Nav({onClick}) {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      onClick={onClick}
      query={worksQuery}
      render={data => <NavContent data={data} {...props} />}
    />
  )
}
```